# MVVM - Layout of View objects (Visual3d) in View or ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a 3D network analysis app in which I want to lay out the vertices of a graph. I follow MVVM as much as possible in this scenario, so my problem is now if I should run the layout algorithm with the vertex ViewModels or the vertex Views (Visual3Ds). The algorithm needs access to the ViewModels anyway to get the respective edges and some other information, so I can get the ViewModel from the View or work with the ViewModels directly. What is the better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to have a ViewModel that contains the points and to bind the Visual3D to it.

That way you can access the the points/edges from with in the ViewModel and see the effect in the View.

This is a very clean way of solving this.

If you would obtain the data from the View, you are breaking the MVVM pattern causing a dependency in the ViewModel on the View making it harder to test the ViewModel.

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing, just needed that confirmation, thank you